# Cannot delete record using laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, query-builder

**I have button delete**

```
{!! Form::open([
                    'route' => ['articles.destroy', $art->id],
                    'method' => 'DELETE',
                    'class' => ''
                ]) !!}
                    <button type="button" class="delete btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> &nbsp;DELETE</button>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**My route :**

```
Route::delete('/articles/delete/{id}', [
'as' => 'articles.destroy',
'uses' => 'ArticlesController@destroy'
```

]);

**My Controller :**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $article = Article::find($id);
    $article->delete();
}
```

My problem is when I click the delete button it doesn't do anything

Comment: Does the form even submit?

Comment: By default `button` will not submit form. `input type="submit"` will.

Comment: yes, I'm forget, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form has to be submitted to call the route. To do this you should change `type="button"` to `type="submit"`.